# hl7 parser with fparsec

Tags: parsing, f#

I have a little experience working with .hl7 data (format for transmitting health data), so I decided to try and write an .hl7 parser using fparsec.

A standard .hl7 segment is a single line with:

1. First 3 chars are the header
2. Next 5 chars are the separators (typically |^~\&)
3. Fields / repetitions delimited by pipes

A segment has fields or repetitions (repeating fields).  A field can have components.   A component can have sub-components.

Sample .hl7 message header:

> ```
> MSH|^~\\&|Location|SendingApp|DateTimeOfMessage
> ```

I am looking for feedback on data design (the types) and the functions.

```
type Subcomponent = {value:string; position:int}
type Component = {subcomponents: Subcomponent list; position:int}
type SingleField = {components: Component list; position:int}
type Field = Repetitions of SingleField list | SingleField of SingleField
type Segment = { name:string; fields:Field list; }
type Hl7Message = { segments:Segment list }

let hl7Seps = "|^~\\&"

let normalChar = noneOf hl7Seps

let unescape c = match c with
                    | 'F' -> '|'
                    | 'R' -> '~'
                    | 'S' -> '^'
                    | 'T' -> '&'
                    | 'E' -> '\\'
                    | c -> c

let escapedChar = attempt (pchar '\\' >>. anyChar |>> unescape .>> skipChar '\\') <|> pchar '\\'

let pHl7Element = manyChars (normalChar <|> escapedChar)

let pcomp = sepBy pHl7Element (pchar '&') |>> (fun vals -> List.mapi (fun i s -> {value = s; position = i}) vals)

let pfield = sepBy pcomp (pchar '^') |>> (fun comps -> List.mapi (fun i c -> {subcomponents = c; position = i}) comps)

let pRepsOrField = sepBy pfield (pchar '~') |>> (fun fields -> match fields.Length with
                                                                | 0 | 1 -> SingleField {components = fields.Item 0; position = 0}
                                                                | _ -> Repetitions (List.mapi (fun i c -> {components = c; position = i}) fields))

let pheader = anyString 3 |>> (fun name -> name)

let pSegment = pipe2 pheader (sepBy pRepsOrField (pchar '|')) (fun name repsOrFields -> {name = name; fields = repsOrFields})

test pSegment "EVN|A&1^B^C|123~456~789"
```

Comment: Ok.  First time on code-review.  Will remove that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really familiar with Fparsec, but a few of your functions could be simplified, or written better:

For example :

```
let pcomp = sepBy pHl7Element (pchar '&') |>> (fun vals -> List.mapi (fun i s -> {value = s; position = i}) vals)
```

Using partial application, it could be written as :

```
let pcomp = sepBy pHl7Element (pchar '&') |>> (List.mapi (fun i s -> { value = s; position = i }))
```

And the one after it:

```
// Before
let pfield = sepBy pcomp (pchar '^') |>> (fun comps -> List.mapi (fun i c -> {subcomponents = c; position = i}) comps)
// After
let pfield = sepBy pcomp (pchar '^') |>> (List.mapi (fun i c -> { subcomponents = c; position = i }))
```

Also, `(fun x -> x)` could be simply replaced by `id`.

```
let pheader = anyString 3 |>> id
```

On other matters, there is a potential bug in your code : in your `pRepsOrField` function, you're matching `field.Length` with `0` then extracting the first item, which will crash your code. Using the `Length` property to find out the length is .. unusual. You don't even need it. Pattern matching with `list`s based on length in F# is usually done this way:

```
match fields with
| [] -> // do something
| [ c ] ->  SingleField { components = c; position = 0 }
| _ -> Repetitions(List.mapi (fun i c -> { components = c; position = i }) fields))
```

Now you don't have to use extra methods/properties to get the length and and the first item. It is all right there ...